# Can you play with players worldwide in Zelda triforce heroes?

Tags: zelda-tri-force-heroes

I was looking at the game's official website, and it said that you can play with players around the world.

[image]

But I also read on a comment on Youtube saying that you could olny play with players in your country.

*(note: I've already posted this before but the game was not released yet so I deleted the question.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it looks like you can only play with people from the same region as you, as the multiplayer is region locked for some security and latency reasons. Maybe the website had some translation error, or they changed it near release.

*Source: http://mynintendonews.com/2015/10/03/online-play-for-the-legend-of-zelda-tri-force-heroes-will-be-region-locked/*

Comment: Specifically the country or just the region (NA/NTSC, EU/PAL, etc)?

Comment: It looks like the region, although I'm not certain.