# American 3ds, but I'm in France

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, region-lock, zelda-tri-force-heroes

I recently asked about zelda tri force heroes being region locked (link here [Can you play with players worldwide in Zelda triforce heroes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240854/can-you-play-with-players-worldwide-in-zelda-triforce-heroes) )

And now I'm wondering, since my **3ds was bought in the USA, and now i'm living in france,** when I play on region locked **online** games (like legend of Zelda tri force heroes). Will I conect to the Amercain servers or the Europe/Australia servers?

Comment: Might have to do some research, but since an American 3DS connects to the American eShop I would say it does the same thing with online gameplay.

Comment: It does connect to the US eshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to answer my own question I think that it would be the USA server because My 3DS connects to the USA eshop (I know it's the USA eshop because it's in dollars)